# How to put two flutter's sparklines charts in one place for example in a card widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I try to display two sparklines that have different data in the same flutter card widget for hours without success. Can anyone help please?
I use the latest flutter_sparkline library.

here is my car

```
             var data = [0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0];

                      Card(
                          elevation: 2,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Sparkline(
                                    data: data,
                                    lineColor: MyColor.outlineInputBorderColor,
                                    pointsMode: PointsMode.all,
                                    pointSize: 8.0,
                                    pointColor: MyColor.Waterbotton,
                                    fallbackWidth: 280,
                                    fallbackHeight: 70,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

here is a picture of what I achieve to do.

[image: picture of what I achieve to do]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      Stack(
            children: [
              Sparkline(
                lineWidth: 5.0,
                lineColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                data: val,
              ),


 Sparkline(
                lineWidth: 5.0,
                lineColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                data: val,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

you can use stack